# Determining if Swift dictionary contains key and obtaining any of its values

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am currently using the following (clumsy) pieces of code for determining if a (non-empty) Swift dictionary contains a given key and for obtaining one (any) value from the same dictionary.

How can one put this more elegantly in Swift?

```
// excerpt from method that determines if dict contains key
if let _ = dict[key] {
    return true
}
else {
    return false
}

// excerpt from method that obtains first value from dict
for (_, value) in dict {
    return value
}
```

Comment: You can use `indexForKey` if you feel it is clearer and more explicit; http://stackoverflow.com/a/29299943/294884

Comment: Very often what you want is basically:  `cityName:String = dict["city"] ?? ""`  The `?? ""` here means basically "if there's no such key, return a blank".

Comment: `Dictionary.keys.contains()` is O(1) for practical purposes (O(n) is worst case.). And more readable than the alternatives here, and handles optional values correctly. See [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/does-dictionary-keys-contains-have-o-1-time-complexity/21647/2).

Comment: It looks like if the SwiftData 'isAutosaveEnabled` is disabled, the `deleteRule` does not work as it should. I disabled it and manually saved the context every time I added or edited any of the model objects and somehow the `deleteRule` does not apply correctly. Also the views does not update correctly.
If I enable it, the view updates correctly (but I still have an issue) and the `deleteRule` apply as expected.

Answer (score 581, accepted):

You don't need *any* special code to do this, because it is what a dictionary already does. When you fetch `dict[key]` you *know* whether the dictionary contains the key, because the Optional that you get back is not `nil` (and it contains the value).

So, if you *just* want to answer the question whether the dictionary contains the key, ask:

```
let keyExists = dict[key] != nil
```

If you want the value and you *know* the dictionary contains the key, say:

```
let val = dict[key]!
```

But if, as usually happens, you don't know it contains the key - you want to fetch it and use it, but only if it exists - then use something like `if let`:

```
if let val = dict[key] {
    // now val is not nil and the Optional has been unwrapped, so use it
}
```

Comment: I don't follow. I just did obtain a value (twice). What more do you want?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first value"; a dictionary is unordered. If you just want the values, without the keys, say `dict.values`.

Comment: Here's the part of my tutorial where I explain about dictionaries: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_dictionary

Comment: My mistake (typo): I meant *any* value. `dict.values` is it then. Thx.

Comment: Here are the parts where I explain about Optionals, which I often illustrate with dictionaries because they return an Optional: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_optional http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_flow_control

Comment: Be careful because `dict.values` is opaque. You can cycle thru it but that's all. (Okay, it's not all, but humor me.) If you want it reified to an Array, take `dict.values.array`.

Comment: You can iterate through the dictionary with a tuple as:  for (key,value) in dict { }.  Also FYI if you want to test for a value and default it you can use the ?? nil coalescing operator:  e.g. var val : String = dict["foo"] ?? "no value".

Comment: @matt if let val = dict[key], dict[key] is not an Optional value so `if let` won't work on it

Comment: @matt Array(dict.keys).contains(key)

Comment: @bubakazouba Try this: `let d = ["hey":"ho"]; let s = d["hey"]; print(s)` It's an Optional, just like it's always been.

Comment: ok i guess i misunderstood the errors messages then, thank you

Comment: sometimes, if the key exists you want to do nothing but if it does not exist you want to add the value with respect to that key. As of swift2.0 it will result in us never using the val (as per ur if) variable. Resulting in a warning that it was never used. Cant we have a inverse of this 'if'.. 'if' this value does not exist.. like explicitly go inside 'if' statement if the val is nill

Comment: @RanaTallal The inverse of `==` is `!=`.

Comment: You can use _ rather than val for the if condition

Comment: What happens if there is a dictionary of [String: Any], for what i read if the object is nil when assigned to Any it would return false always https://forums.swift.org/t/any-should-never-be-nil/11636, is there a way to validate key exist, even if we don't know the type, or do we always need to perform the cast to avoid that Any == nil `false` condition ?

Comment: @Kross That is a very profound question but therefore please ask it separately.

Comment: Just a note to use `index(forKey: k) != nil` if you need to deal with [@Bergy's concern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48228186/125349)

Answer (score 96):

Why not simply check for `dict.keys.contains(key)`?
Checking for `dict[key] != nil` will not work in cases where the value is nil.
As with a dictionary `[String: String?]` for example.

Comment: Or instead of just writing `if let val = dict[key]` you can use `if let val = dict[key] as? String` in this case.

Comment: .keys.contains does not help to distinguish whether key exists, or if value is nil. Maybe in earlier swift versions? Doesn't work for me in swift 4.

Comment: This is potentially very wasteful, because (1) you call `dict.keys` that creates an array with all the keys, then (2) checks every key in order until you find one (or none!). I realize you are trying to address the case of a `[String: String?]`, but would be very careful with that solution...

Comment: As @charles mentioned, this would eliminate the fast lookup benefit that using a dictionary provides so I'd advise against this one, but still definitely a valid option.

Comment: See also comment from @jedwidz below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129401/determining-if-swift-dictionary-contains-key-and-obtaining-any-of-its-values#comment92233227_48228186  Checking == nil does work, even if the dictionary has optional values, so there is really no reason to do the above.

Comment: You should **never** use this method, in has complexity O(n) instead of theoretical (depends on hash function implementation) O(1) of direct dictionary access.

Comment: @charles I don't see anywhere in the docs for [keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894263-keys) that it says it creates an array or that `contains` is O(n). It says it's a view, but doesn't seem to indicate its performance characteristics. Hopefully, it doesn't make a copy and is O(1).

Comment: @EdwardBrey Good point, I took the worst case implementation (completely misinformed by the ObjC version that returns NSArray), but who knows, it might be optimized for that use. Or not, of course :) It would be interesting to look at the implementation, since it's open source...

Comment: @EdwardBrey Ah, we can get the answer straight from the documentation, in fact, where it says that `contains` is O(n), yikes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/keys/2892604-contains

Comment: @charles so contains having O(n) lookup is correct (its just the collection conformance implementation), but allocating a new array just for accessing "keys" doesn't appear correct. Can you fix that?

Comment: `Dictionary.keys` is a custom sequence, and for practical considerations`Dictionary.keys.contains` is O(1). The documentation is giving the worst case value of O(n). See [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/does-dictionary-keys-contains-have-o-1-time-complexity/21647/2).

Comment: `.contains(where:)` is a method of Sequence protocol, which provides linear access to elements. Average access time is O(n), there is no way around it. For proper performance you need to use some method of Dictionary itself. 

But Swift being Swift, I see no obvious way to distinguish between nil because of no key and nil because key is present, but value is optional and nil

Comment: It might be an Apple Doc oversight, but per testing it has amortized O(1) time complexity. Source: https://forums.swift.org/t/does-dictionary-keys-contains-have-o-1-time-complexity/21647/14 and https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0154-dictionary-key-and-value-collections.md#proposed-solution

Answer (score 85):

The accepted answer `let keyExists = dict[key] != nil` will not work if the Dictionary contains the key but has a value of nil.

If you want to be sure the Dictionary does not contain the key at all use this (tested in Swift 4).

```
if dict.keys.contains(key) {
  // contains key
} else { 
  // does not contain key
}
```

Comment: This is the same as Han's answer.

Comment: Checking `== nil` does work, even if the dictionary has optional values. This is because the lookup result is wrapped as an `Optional`. On the other hand, to check if the looked up value is really `nil` rather than absent, you can use `== .some(nil)`.

Comment: I would add the efficiency of using this method compared to the  O(1) lookup of the other methods. I believe it’s O(n) lookup

Comment: @AlbertoVega-MSFT It's [`O(1)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5bf69b356c320d77784427108bb92573847de346/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift#L1342-L1346). See also: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0154-dictionary-key-and-value-collections.md#proposed-solution What made you think it was `O(n)`?

Comment: @Alexander and what is there about `contains` and `O(1)` complexity?
Btw, in docs, about `contains`: O(n), where n is the length of the sequence.

Comment: @dimpiax Read the whole thing. It talks about how `keys` used to be implemented as a `LazyMapCollection` (basically just `dict.lazy.map { key, value in key }` that had no way of efficiently fowardining "contains" checks to the referenced dictionary. Instead, they implemented a new type `Dictionary.Keys`, which presents a Collection-conforming view onto the underlying dictionary's keys, with O(1) contains checks.

Comment: The documentation for the `Dictionary.Keys.contains(...)` function [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/keys/2892604-contains) says it has `O(n)` complexity, where `n` is the length of the sequence.

Comment: @jedwidz as you mention == nil works but not for [String: Any] where any can't be nil
https://forums.swift.org/t/any-should-never-be-nil/11636

Comment: `Dictionary.keys` is a custom sequence, and for practical considerations`Dictionary.keys.contains` is O(1). The documentation is giving the worst case value of O(n). See [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/does-dictionary-keys-contains-have-o-1-time-complexity/21647/2).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you got what you need from @matt, but if you want a quick way to get a value for a key, or just the first value if that key doesn’t exist:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func keyedOrFirstValue(key: Key) -> Value? {
        // if key not found, replace the nil with 
        // the first element of the values collection
        return self[key] ?? first(self.values)
        // note, this is still an optional (because the
        // dictionary could be empty)
    }
}

let d = ["one":"red", "two":"blue"]

d.keyedOrFirstValue("one")  // {Some "red"}
d.keyedOrFirstValue("two")  // {Some "blue"}
d.keyedOrFirstValue("three")  // {Some "red”}
```

Note, no guarantees what you'll actually get as the first value, it just happens in this case to return “red”.

Comment: good use of the `??` operator took my convenience solution from me, but as an extension that default value could present data insecurities or unexpected behaviors. That sounds like something a concrete subclass of `Dictionary` ought to employ. How often do you need the first value in case of a `nil` return excluding situation specific functionality?

Answer (score 1):

My solution for a cache implementation that stores optional NSAttributedString:

```
public static var attributedMessageTextCache    = [String: NSAttributedString?]()

    if attributedMessageTextCache.index(forKey: "key") != nil
    {
        if let attributedMessageText = TextChatCache.attributedMessageTextCache["key"]
        {
            return attributedMessageText
        }
        return nil
    }

    TextChatCache.attributedMessageTextCache["key"] = .some(.none)
    return nil
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the value of the key you can use this extension

```
extension Dictionary {
    func containsKey(_ key: Key) -> Value? {
        if let index = index(forKey: key){
            return self.values[index]
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this any different from doing `dictionary["key"]`?

Answer (score -1):

If you are dealing with dictionary that may contain nil value for a key then you can check existence of key by:

```swift
dictionay.index(forKey: item.key) != nil
```

For getting first value in dictionary:

```swift
dictionay.first?.value // optional since dictionary might be empty
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if dictionayTemp["quantity"] != nil
    {

  //write your code
    }
```

Comment: This is often what you want. It means **it DOES exist >>>>AND<<<<< the value is NOT nil**