# Check if key exists in dictionary of type [Type:Type?]

Tags: swift

How can I check if a key exists in a dictionary? My dictionary is of type `[Type:Type?]`.

I can't simply check `dictionary[key] == nil`, as that could result from the value being `nil`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Actually your test `dictionary[key] == nil` *can* be used to check
if a key exists in a dictionary. It will not yield `true` if the value
is set to `nil`:

```
let dict : [String : Int?] = ["a" : 1, "b" : nil]

dict["a"] == nil // false,     dict["a"] is .some(.some(1))
dict["b"] == nil // false !!,  dict["b"] is .some(.none)
dict["c"] == nil // true,      dict["c"] is .none
```

To distinguish between "key is not present in dict" and "value for key is nil" you
can do a nested optional assignment:

```
if let val = dict["key"] {
    if let x = val {
        print(x)
    } else {
        print("value is nil")
    }
} else {
    print("key is not present in dict")
}
```

Comment: Wow this is crazy. Why does `dict["b"] == nil` evaluate to false?

Comment: @vrwim: `dict["b"]` is a "nested optional" and has the type `Int??`, the real value is `.Some(.None<Int>)` :) You can read more about it in the Swift blog https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=12. See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27226589/1187415 to a related question.

Comment: Nice, but I think this might cause some problems in the future. Glad that I know this exists.

Comment: This is correct.  I'm not sure why someone would down vote this.

Comment: @MartinR. How to check Dictionary key exist in NSarray? without comparing each member. can i use contains method?.

Comment: This works, however, dictionary.indexForKey is more deterministic and easier to understand. Right?

Comment: @thatjuan: Why compute an index if you are only interested in the existence? `dict[key] != nil` checks if the dictionary has a value for the given key, no matter if the values itself have optional type or not. I don't know what you mean by "more deterministic". – But anyway, use what you are more familiar with, both methods work!

Comment: @MartinR I think "Deterministic" was not the best word. What I meant is that reading `dict[key] != nil` can be misinterpreted as a check for the value being null, rather than the key not existing (because it's a nested optional as you pointed out).

Comment: @thatjuan: And I see it like this: the dictionary subscript methods return an optional which is `nil` if the key does not exist. It does not matter what type the value itself has. The index of the key (if it exists) is not asked for (and has limited use for dictionaries anyway). But as I said: both methods work, use what *you* feel better with :)

Comment: say @MartinR - has any of this changed in Swift3, do you reckon ??

Comment: @JoeBlow: It works the same in Swift 2 and 3. What would you expect to change?

Comment: I don't know!  :)  But thanks a million for letting me know it has not changed.  @MartinR

Comment: For example, they may have added a ".hasKey" method, say.  @MartinR

Comment: @JoeBlow: `dict.keys.contains(key)` would be another option (Swift 2+3).

Comment: @JoeBlow, but that's O(*n*) and thus too slow.

Comment: This methodology seems invalid in Swift 5.2? - https://i.imgur.com/SWd9XbE.png

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: I no not think that anything changed here in newer Swift versions. `dict["key"] = nil` will remove the key (and associated value) from the dictionary. `dict["key"] = nil as Int?` or `dict["key"] = Optional<Int>.none`  assigns the value `Optional<Int>.none` to the key.

Answer (score 47):

I believe the Dictionary type's `indexForKey(key: Key)` is what you're looking for. It returns the index for a given key, but more importantly for your proposes, it returns nil if it can't find the specified key in the dictionary.

```
if dictionary.indexForKey("someKey") != nil {
    // the key exists in the dictionary
}
```

Swift 3 syntax....

```
if dictionary.index(forKey: "someKey") == nil {
    print("the key 'someKey' is NOT in the dictionary")
}
```

Comment: I agree that this is explicit and clear.  In many situations it may be the best idiom.

Comment: this is very easy on the eyes

Comment: I think `dictionary.keys.contains("someKey")` is more clear. It has the same behavior with nil values too.

Comment: @Austin unfortunately that pattern is very slow, since it's a linear search of `keys` which is an array-like value.

Comment: @PatrickBeard It actually does have the same performance as 'indexForKey()'. There’s some discussion here: https://forums.swift.org/t/does-dictionary-keys-contains-have-o-1-time-complexity/21647/2

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Still, .index(forKey:) is advertised as being O(1), and you have to dig to find that out. If I don't need all of the keys, requesting a view of them seems more expensive. But perhaps it doesn't have to allocate any memory.

Answer (score 4):

You can always do:

```
let arrayOfKeys = dictionary.allKeys
if arrayOfKeys.containsObject(yourKey) {

}
else {
}
```

However I really dislike the idea of creating an NSDictionary which can contain optionals.

Comment: This is Objective-C code and I wanted to know the answer on a Swift Dictionary.

Comment: Where is this Objective-C? Here's the allKeys method in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDictionary/allKeys and here's the contains object method: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject: . I expected you to be capable of declaring an `NSArray`...

Comment: I would like to use the Swift types, not NSArray

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let value = dict[key] != nil
```

Hope it work for you. Thanks

Comment: Like many has pointed out, if the value is nil this wont work. If value cant be nil this is great 

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129401/determining-if-swift-dictionary-contains-key-and-obtaining-any-of-its-values) and [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29299943/2883267), the best solution is to use `Dictionary.index(forKey:)` which returns `Dictionary<Key, Value>.Index?`. Regardless of whether your value is an optional type, this returns an optional index, which if `nil`, definitively tells you whether the key exists in the dictionary or not. This is *much more* efficient than using `Dictionary.contains(where:)` which is documented to have "complexity O(*n*), where *n* is the length of the sequence."

So, a much better way to write `.containsKey()` would be:

```
extension Dictionary {
  func contains(key: Key) -> Bool {
    self.index(forKey: key) != nil
  }
}
```

I've been advised that [dict.keys.contains() is actually O(1)](https://forums.swift.org/t/does-dictionary-keys-contains-have-o-1-time-complexity/21647/2), so feel free to use it if you prefer.

Answer (score -2):

I handled it this way in Swift 4:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func contains(key: Key) -> Bool {
        let value = self.contains { (k,_) -> Bool in key == k }
        return value
    }
}
```

This uses `Dictionary.contains(where: (key: Hashable, value: Value) throws -> Bool)`. By encapsulating it as an extension I have a good shot at updating the implementation to something better without modifying my code. I'm avoiding creating data, which `index(forKey:Key)` does. I'm hoping it's more efficient than accessing `keys` since that must create the whole array before searching it.

Comment: See above. The `keys` property returns an *array-like* view on the keys, and its `.contains()` method runs in O(1) time, taking advantage of the underlying hash table. Unfortunately using `.contains(where:)` is O(*n*) because it keeps running the predicate until a key matches.