# Optional Type Dictionary yields "Value of Optional type not unwrapped"

Tags: ios, swift

Why does this:

```
let optionalInts: [Int: Int?] = [ 0: 0 ]
let regularInt: Int = optionalInts[0]!
```

Give me this compile-time error:

> Error: Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

But this works:

```
let optionalInts: [Int: Int?] = [ 0: 0 ]
let regularInt: Int = optionalInts[0]!! // <-- notice the double "!!"
```

Comment: As I think - in second variable you are just wrapping the value of 'Single Int', so what about 'Second Int? (optional one)'. To wrap the second one you need to put that exclamation.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299727/check-if-key-exists-in-dictionary-of-type-typetype.

Comment: You can do like this too `let optionalInts: [Int: Int?] = [ 0: 0 ] - let regularInt: [Int: Int?] = optionalInts[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, but the value in a `Dictionary` is already optional, so making the value optional:

```
let optionalInts: [Int: Int?] = [ 0: 0 ]
```

Is redundant, making the value a double-optional, similar to:

```
let doubleOptionalInt: Optional<Optional<Int>> = 0
```

So what you need to do is drop the optional:

```
let optionalInts: [Int: Int] = [ 0: 0 ]
```

Maybe (or maybe not) surprisingly, you can recursively box optionals indefinitely:

```
let wayTooManyOptionalsInt: Int?????????????? = 0
```

And would require the same number of `!` to unwrap it back to an `Int`:

```
let backToInt: Int = wayTooManyOptionalsInt!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```