# Cannot assign value of type 'String??' to type 'String?' error

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift-optionals

let say I defined a class

```
class Dummy {

    var title: String?
}
```

and I have a dictionary as

```
let foo: [Int: String?]  = [:]
```

then when I make an assignment as below

```
var dummy = Dummy()

dummy.title = foo[1]
```

it says

> Cannot assign value of type 'String??' to type 'String?'
>
> Insert ' as! String'

return type of `foo` is `String?` and `Dictionary` returns optional of its value type when used subscript but what is `String??` type in swift?

I think it should be legal to make such assignment.
Why it complains and how should I make this assignment

Comment: Compare [Two (or more) optionals in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27225232/1187415).

Comment: You defined the value type as an optional, therefore there is a difference between “the dictionary does not have a value for that key” and “the  dictionary value for that key exists and  is nil”. I demonstrated the difference in my answer to the above mentioned Q&A.

Comment: Also related: [Check if key exists in dictionary of type `[Type:Type?]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29299727/1187415).

Answer (score 0):

Since having a value corresponding to the key 1 in the dictionary `foo` is optional and the value in the dictionary is of type `String?` it returns type `String??`. Unwrapping the value once to check if the value exists would fix this issue

```
if let value = foo[1] {
    dummy.title = value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By declaring your dictionary as `[Int:String?]` you are saying that the key is an `Int` and values are optional `String`s.  Now the key may not be present in the dictionary, so `foo[1]` optionally returns an optional and you end up with an with an optional optional - `String??`

Now while there are sometimes uses for optional optionals, I don't think that is what you want in this case.

You can simply make a dictionary of `[Int:String]` and then not insert an element if the value is `nil`.

```
let foo: [Int: String]  = [:]
dummy.title = foo[1]
```

If you do need to handle the case where "there is a value for this key and it is `nil`" then the nil-coalescing operator may help you:

```
dummy.title = foo[1] ?? nil
```

or even

```
dummy.title = foo[1] ?? ""
```

Comment: Class and variables in this question are demonstration purpose, in my actual case, it is not same to having a key in dictionary and value equals to `nil` and not having the key in dictionary, but in some cases it does not matter. I tought swift could convert `Optional<Optional<String>>.none` to `Optional<String>.none`

Comment: No, there is clearly a semantic difference between "there is no value for this key" and "there is a value for this key and it is `nil`"