# Swift dictionary with assigned nil value can be conditionally bind in if let statement

Tags: swift, dictionary, if-statement, conditional-binding

Can you explain this Swift code

If I assign nil value for "a" key
and then use if let statement this nil value will be unwrapped as nil and can be printed

```
import Foundation
var dictionary = ["a": nil, "b": "Costam", "c": nil]
dictionary.updateValue(nil, forKey: "a")

if let value = dictionary["b"] { 
   print("Some value: ", value)
}

print(dictionary.keys)
```

And to prevent this behaviour I need to add typecasting to String?

```
import Foundation
var dictionary = ["a": nil, "b": "Costam", "c": nil]
dictionary.updateValue(nil, forKey: "a")

if let value = dictionary["b"] as? String { 
   print("Some value: ", value)
}

print(dictionary.keys)
```

Comment: Well this is exactly why Optional dictionary values are a bad idea. They serve no purpose so just don't do it.

Comment: Related: [Check if key exists in dictionary of type `[Type:Type?]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29299727/1187415).

Comment: Yeah, I'd say don't use `[Type:Type?]`. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

If I put your first snippet into a playground, I see the warning: "Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'".  So, nothing is being automatically unwrapped and, in fact, if I get rid of the warning by force unwrapping, it crashes (as expected).

Your dictionary data type is [String:String?] and `value` is String?.  When you don't tell the compiler what you want, it decides on something relatively safe.  Only when you're explicit does it check if the specified conversion can work.