# Swift 2.0 conditional assignment and syntax

Tags: swift, if-statement

The following code works (where `someArray.objectForKey("someKey")` is of type `NSNumber`):

```
var someInt:Int = 123

if(someDict["someKey"] != nil) {
    someInt = someDict["someKey"]!.integerValue
}
```

So that works and does what I need it to do but I am almost 100% sure this isn't the way it's supposed to be done in Swift.

I'm looking for a more elegant solution to the above code.

Comment: Check the answer in the following link it might helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129401/determining-if-swift-dictionary-contains-key-and-obtaining-any-of-its-values

Comment: So `someArray` is a *dictionary*??

Answer (score 3):

It's called Optional Binding

```
if let someValue = someArray["someKey"] as? Int { 
   someInt = someValue 
}
```

Please read the section about Optional Binding in [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do

```
if let someInt = someArray.objectForKey("someKey")?.integerValue {

}
```

Or

```
someInt = someArray.objectForKey("someKey")?.integerValue ?? 0
```

Where 0 is a default value that gets assigned to `someInt` if `objectForKey` returns nil.

Comment: This is very interesting, I shall experiment!

Comment: When you start experimenting, also try `guard let` @Parad0x13

Comment: Okay after experimenting I REALLY like your 2nd example. Since I already have a default value for somInt I've changed your code to:

    someInt = someDict["someKey"]?.integerValue ?? someInt

This seems to work flawlessly thank you