# How would I be able to ensure json elements are not nil?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, parsing

I've tried to use optional binding in my code but it still comes up as nil when I execute and debug so I was wondering if I have used an incorrect method?

[Here is the code which shows me trying to parse my JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0nHr.png)

Here's the code which I use to try and parse my JSON:

```
import Foundation

protocol ListingModelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class ListingModel: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

    weak var delegate: ListingModelProtocol!

    var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    let urlPath: String = "http://booksmart.hol.es/service.php" // this will be changed to the path where service.php lives


    func downloadItems() {

        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var session: NSURLSession!
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()


        session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url)

        task.resume()

    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        self.data.appendData(data);

    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to download data")
        }else {
            print("Data downloaded")
            self.parseJSON()
        }



    }
    func parseJSON() {

        var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
        let properties: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        for(var i = 0; i < jsonResult.count; i+=1)
        {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let property = PropertyModel()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let propertyType = jsonElement["Property Type"] as? String,
                let price = jsonElement["Price"] as? String,
                let distance = jsonElement["Distance"] as? String

            {

                property.propertyType = propertyType
                property.price = price
                property.distance = distance


            }

            properties.addObject(property)

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(properties)

        })
    }
}
```

Here's the code I use to download data from my database:

```
import Foundation

class PropertyModel: NSObject {

    //properties

    var propertyType: String?
    var price: String?
    var distance: String?


    //empty constructor

    override init()
    {

    }

    //construct with @propertyType, @price and @distance parameters

    init(propertyType: String, price: String, distance: String) {

        self.propertyType = propertyType
        self.price = price
        self.distance = distance

    }


    //prints object's current state

    override var description: String {
        return "Property Type: \(propertyType), Price: \(price), Distance: \(distance)"

    }


}
```

And finally here's the code I use to try and get this into table cells in swift:

```
import UIKit

class First_ResultsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,    ListingModelProtocol  {

    //Properties

    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
    var selectedProperties : PropertyModel = PropertyModel()
    @IBOutlet weak var PropertyListTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //set delegates and initialize homeModel

        self.PropertyListTableView.delegate = self
        self.PropertyListTableView.dataSource = self

        let listingModel = ListingModel()
        listingModel.delegate = self
        listingModel.downloadItems()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

        feedItems = items
        self.PropertyListTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items
        return feedItems.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)!
        // Get the location to be shown
        let item: PropertyModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! PropertyModel
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = item.propertyType

        return myCell
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */


}
```

Comment: have you looked here ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28129484/1585677

Comment: Please post your code rather as text, not the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code that you post and your comment, is not correct.

```
//the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
if let propertyType = jsonElement["Property Type"] as? String,
    let price = jsonElement["Price"] as? String,
    let distance = jsonElement["Distance"] as? String
```

The above is not ensuring that the values are not `nil`. Your `if` statement is checking that if all of this jsonElement is not `nil` then it will enter and set your properties.

Also, if any of the above properties is not a String in ur json response, it will not enter the `if` statement. You should be checking it with the type you return. Replace the `as? Double` with the type your json response return.

```
if let propertyType = jsonElement["Property Type"] as? String,
    let price = jsonElement["Price"] as? Double,
    let distance = jsonElement["Distance"] as? Double {

    property.propertyType = propertyType
    property.price = "\(price)"
    property.distance = "\(distance)"
 }
```

If you want to set it to a empty string when is `nil`, you should be using the `as String ?? ""`.

```
//the following ensure that when the element is nil, we change it to a empty string and update our attributes
 let propertyType = jsonElement["Property Type"] as? String ?? ""
 let price = jsonElement["Price"] as? String ?? ""
 let distance = jsonElement["Distance"] as? String? ??

property.propertyType = propertyType
property.price = price
property.distance = distance
```

You no longer need the `if` statement anymore as it will not be nil.

Comment: However the problem is that there are values in the database so none of the variable should be nil? I just want to add the values at are in the database to these variables and show them in the table cells

Comment: Have u debug and look into the jsonElements and see if all variable exist like in ur database?

Comment: Looking at it again, maybe it is because the json response for `price` and `distance` is not a string. Therefore it is not there. I will update my answer now. Let me know what is the `price` and `distance` in your database? @AdamKona

Comment: I've used the same data type for all the data in my table (VARCHAR) so i'm not quite sure why this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are using an optional binding condition (`if let`) to retrieve those json values if they are not nil and are of the right type.

But what happens if that is not the case and one or more of those json keys are missing or contain the wrong type of value? What it looks like is that your empty `PropertyModel` still gets added to your `properties` array, but since `propertyType`, `price`, and `distance` were never set (and it sounds like they are optional), they will have their default values which are mostly likely nil.

You should move the line `properties.addObject(property)` up to be inside the `if let` condition block (directly under `property.distance = distance` and above `}`).  Then you won't add any PropertyModels with nil values to your array.

Comment: When I do that it no longer puts the properties into the table view (which is the ultimate goal), but in fact creates none. i've added more code above so that it can all be looked at properly

Comment: @AdamKona If doing that results in no PoropertyModel objects, then either your json has an error (missing one or more of the keys you are looking for) or your code is trying to cast one or more of the values to strings when they are numbers in your json, or your code is trying to access the wrong name for one or more keys. Can you post an example of the json you are parsing?