# Checking key in JSONObject Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am new in Swift. How to check the key from JSONObject is exist? In Java I can do this `jsonObject.has("selected")` . Below my code :

```
currTable = filteredDataTable[indexPath.row] as! [AnyHashable: Any]

if ((currTable.index(forKey: "selected") != nil) /*currTable["selected"]) != nil*/) {
          currTable.updateValue((!((currTable["selected"] as? Bool)!)), forKey: "selected")
}
else {
          currTable.updateValue(true, forKey: "selected")
}
print(currTable)
```

In my code above, it always give me `else` condition when I click my CollectionView Cell. So the `selected` key in my JSONObject always true. Have I made a mistake? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129401/determining-if-swift-dictionary-contains-key-and-obtaining-any-of-its-values#_=_) but its not clear all of my problem.

Comment: it looks as if the currTable dictionary does not have a key named "selected". Have you set a breakpoint on the if condition and checked to see what your data is like and why the key is not set? It might be that you either are not initializing with a value for "selected" or your condition should be == nil?

Comment: Are you try use  "expr(bool) ? expr : expr" or "if let/guard let"?

Comment: @Fahim its absolutely right. the `currTable` is never have `selected` key. So i want to put that and give the value . But its seems not work

Comment: @Evsenev no i not yet try that. I will read about `guard` Sorry for my bad english

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta OK, then, reverse your condition - if you start out without the "selected" key, then look for == nil and set the value to true for the selected key when you select a row. Since you start out without anything selected (at least I think you do), then setting "selected" should introduce the key to the dictionary. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Fahim hmm, i have this code work in java android. the currTable is never have selected at the begin. When i clicked one of collectionview its will check is `selected` `key` exist. If exist i give it true directly. But if its not, i put `selected` and give the value invers of the `selected` key. please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
currTable = filteredDataTable[indexPath.row] as! [AnyObject: Any]

if let selectedTableElement = currTable["selected"] != nil {
    currTable.updateValue(false, forKey: "selected") 
}
else {
    currTable.updateValue(true, forKey: "selected")
}
print(currTable)
```

Comment: what is selectedTableElement?

Comment: just a constant to check nil in conditional , but it will not change anything in your functionality .

Comment: Can use  `_` instead of unused term. 
Anw, `if let _ = currTable["selected"] { } is enough i think

Comment: how you read that? if selectedTableElement same with currTable which have selected key exist ? thanks before but i think this not work for me