# How to use Swift JSONDecode with dynamic types?

Tags: json, swift, decode, encode

My App has a local cache and sends/receives models from/to the server. So I decided to build a map [String : Codable.Type], essentially to be able to decode anything I have on this generic cache either created locally or received from server.

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
var modelNameToType = [String : Codable.Type]()
modelNameToType = ["ContactModel": ContactModel.Self, "AnythingModel" : AnythingModel.Self, ...]
```

Whatever I create on the App I can encode successfully and store on cache like this:

```
let contact = ContactModel(name: "John")
let data = try! encoder.encode(contact)
CRUD.shared.storekey(key: "ContactModel$10", contact)
```

I would like to decode like this:

```
let result = try! decoder.decode(modelNameToType["ContactModel"]!, from: data)
```

But I get the error:

> Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type (Codable.Type,
>   from: Data)

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated

Fixing the type works, and solves any local request, but not a remote request.

```
let result = try! decoder.decode(ContactModel.self, from: data)
```

Contact Model:

```
struct ContactModel: Codable {
    var name : String
}
```

For remote requests I would have a function like this:

```
    func buildAnswer(keys: [String]) -> Data {

        var result = [String:Codable]()
        for key in keys {
            let data = CRUD.shared.restoreKey(key: key)
            let item = try decoder.decode(modelNameToType[key]!, from: data)
            result[key] = item
        }
        return try encoder.encode(result)
    }
```

...if I solve the decode issue. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How this "decoder.decode(ContactModel.self, from: data)" doesn't work still ? This one looks correct.
Please also post your ContactModel class definition please.

Comment: I was just stating that decoder.decode(ContactModel.self, from: data) does work!

Comment: When you say "dynamic", what type do you expect `result` to be? (It has to be a specific type at compile-time. It can't be "whatever the type works out to be at runtime." If it were "some random type not known at compile-time" what methods could you call on it? In other words, what would be the next line of code that used `result`?)

Comment: This app has a local cache and every so often receives and sends info to the server.  I will update the question to have the whole func as you suggested

Comment: I understand it is kind of inverted, confusing, usually the server does the answering, and the app does the questioning, but in this case I have both situations.

Comment: This is tightly related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234233/5555803)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Codable` API is built around encoding from and decoding into *concrete* types. However, the round-tripping you want here shouldn't have to know about any concrete types; it's merely concatenating heterogenous JSON values into a JSON object.

Therefore, `JSONSerialization` is a better tool for the job in this case, as it deals with `Any`:

```
import Foundation

// I would consider lifting your String keys into their own type btw.
func buildAnswer(keys: [String]) throws -> Data {

  var result = [String: Any](minimumCapacity: keys.count)

  for key in keys {
    let data = CRUD.shared.restoreKey(key: key)
    result[key] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
  }
  return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result)
}
```

---

That being said, you *could* still make this with `JSONDecoder`/`JSONEncoder` – however it requires quite a bit of type-erasing boilerplate.

For example, we need a wrapper type that conforms to `Encodable`, as `Encodable` [doesn't conform to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878):

```
import Foundation

struct AnyCodable : Encodable {

  private let _encode: (Encoder) throws -> Void

  let base: Codable
  let codableType: AnyCodableType

  init<Base : Codable>(_ base: Base) {
    self.base = base
    self._encode = {
      var container = $0.singleValueContainer()
      try container.encode(base)
    }
    self.codableType = AnyCodableType(type(of: base))
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    try _encode(encoder)
  }
}
```

We also need a wrapper to capture a concrete type that can be used for decoding:

```
struct AnyCodableType {

  private let _decodeJSON: (JSONDecoder, Data) throws -> AnyCodable
  // repeat for other decoders...
  // (unfortunately I don't believe there's an easy way to make this generic)
  //

  let base: Codable.Type

  init<Base : Codable>(_ base: Base.Type) {
    self.base = base
    self._decodeJSON = { decoder, data in
      AnyCodable(try decoder.decode(base, from: data))
    }
  }

  func decode(from decoder: JSONDecoder, data: Data) throws -> AnyCodable {
    return try _decodeJSON(decoder, data)
  }
}
```

We cannot simply pass a `Decodable.Type` to `JSONDecoder`'s

```
func decode<T : Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T
```

as when `T` is a protocol type, the `type:` parameter takes a `.Protocol` metatype, not a `.Type` metatype (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234233/5555803) for more info).

We can now define a type for our keys, with a `modelType` property that returns an `AnyCodableType` that we can use for decoding JSON:

```
enum ModelName : String {

  case contactModel = "ContactModel"
  case anythingModel = "AnythingModel"

  var modelType: AnyCodableType {
    switch self {
    case .contactModel:
      return AnyCodableType(ContactModel.self)
    case .anythingModel:
      return AnyCodableType(AnythingModel.self)
    }
  }
}
```

and then do something like this for the round-tripping:

```
func buildAnswer(keys: [ModelName]) throws -> Data {

  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()

  var result = [String: AnyCodable](minimumCapacity: keys.count)

  for key in keys {
    let rawValue = key.rawValue
    let data = CRUD.shared.restoreKey(key: rawValue)
    result[rawValue] = try key.modelType.decode(from: decoder, data: data)
  }
  return try encoder.encode(result)
}
```

This probably could be designed better to work *with* `Codable` rather than against it (perhaps a struct to represent the JSON object you send to the server, and use key paths to interact with the caching layer), but without knowing more about `CRUD.shared` and how you use it; it's hard to say.

Comment: Thank you Hamish.  Nicely understood and answered.  I didn't see this language behaviour coming, but I confess that I don't have as much experience with Swift as with other languages.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to decode like this:
>
> ```
> let result = try! decoder.decode(modelNameToType["ContactModel"]!, from: data)
> ```
>
> But I get the error:
>
> ```
> Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type (Codable.Type, from: Data)
> ```

You are using `decode` incorrectly. The first parameter to `decoder.decode` must not be an *object*; it must be a *type*. You cannot pass a metatype wrapped up in an expression.

You can, however, pass an *object* and take its type. So you could solve this with a generic that guarantees that we are a Decodable adopter. Here's a minimal example:

```
func testing<T:Decodable>(_ t:T, _ data:Data) {
    let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(type(of:t), from: data)
    // ...
}
```

If you pass a ContactModel instance as the first parameter, that's legal.

Comment: Revised my answer to suggest using a generic and `type(of:)`.

Comment: Hey matt, in that case I would need to store an object on the dictionary [string:any].  But when I do type(of: dictionary[key]) I get Any? as result.

Comment: @RodrigoFava So unwrap it! `type(of: dictionary[key]!)` (Except you should unwrap safely.) The type of an Optional Any is Optional Any. But unwrap the Optional, you've got an Any, and now `type(of:)` takes the underlying type correctly.

Comment: Except of course you really should unwrap it safely, as I explain here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28129484/341994

Comment: Let's say I have entry ["contact": ContactModel.Self], type(of: dictionary["contact]!)  is yielding Any.Type, not ContactModel.Type

Comment: You have misunderstood my answer. I say supply a ContactModel _instance_, not a type. Read the last sentence of my answer. Read it carefully. Aloud.

Comment: `let d = ["string":"anotherString"]; print(type(of:d["string"]!))` yields `String`. And that is so even if `d` is typed as `[String:Any]`. Your move.

Comment: For every model type we will have the expense of +1 instance ... Can it be done with a closure?

Comment: The point is only that you can’t do what you originally proposed to do. The language doesn’t permit it. Thus you need an alternative. I proposed one. Hamish proposed one. Pick one. Or neither.

Comment: I did implement my alternative, as well as I am taking the chance to learn more about the language.  No offenses meant, and thank you anyway. I will give you the credit for the answer.

Comment: There is little reason to pass `type(of:)` to `JSONDecoder.decode` or other generic functions. It is common practice to add a `T.Type` parameter to generic functions to allow callers to specify a generic type (specializing `f<T>() -> T` in the obvious way by writing `f<String>()` is invalid), but this parameter is almost always ignored in the implementation. `JSONDecoder().decode(type(of:t), from: data)` and `JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)` decode in exactly the same way.

Comment: See the [implementation of `JSONDecoder`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/JSONDecoder.swift) for how exactly this type parameter is used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution similar to @Hamish's `AnyCodable` solution which requires less work but only works for classes.

```swift
typealias DynamicCodable = AnyObject & Codable

extension Decodable {
    static func decode<K: CodingKey>(from container: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>, forKey key: K) throws -> Self {
        try container.decode(Self.self, forKey: key)
    }
}
extension Encodable {
    func encode<K: CodingKey>(to container: inout KeyedEncodingContainer<K>, forKey key: K) throws {
        try container.encode(self, forKey: key)
    }
}

struct AnyDynamicCodable: Codable {
    let value: DynamicCodable
    
    init(_ value: DynamicCodable) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
        case value
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let typeName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        guard let type = NSClassFromString(typeName) as? DynamicCodable.Type else {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(DynamicCodable.Type.self, .init(codingPath: decoder.codingPath + [CodingKeys.type], debugDescription: "NSClassFromString returned nil or did not conform to DynamicCodable.", underlyingError: nil))
        }
        self.value = try type.decode(from: container, forKey: .value)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let typeName: String = NSStringFromClass(type(of: self.value))
        try container.encode(typeName, forKey: .type)
        try self.value.encode(to: &container, forKey: .value)
    }
}
```

This relies on a few features.

First, if a value is an object, then it's type can be converted to a `String` with `NSStringFromClass` and recovered later with `NSClassFromString`. Honestly, I am not sure how safe this is, but this approach seems to work for me in the limited testing I have done. I have asked about this in a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68075707/are-nsclassfromstring-and-nsstringfromclass-guaranteed-to-be-inverses-across).
This lets us encode and decode the type of an object.

Once we have a type, we would like to be able to decode a value of this type like so:

```swift
let value = try container.decode(type, forKey .value)
```

but this is not possible. The reason is that `KeyedDecodingContainer.decode` is a generic function whose type argument must be known at compile time. This leads us to

```swift
extension Decodable {
    static func decode<K: CodingKey>(from container: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>, forKey key: K) throws -> Self {
        try container.decode(Self.self, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

which then enables us to write

```swift
let value = try type.decode(from: container, forKey: .value)
```

instead.

This is a very general technique. If you need to plug a dynamic (runtime) type into a generic function, wrap it in an extension on the type constraints of the generic function. Unfortunately, you will not be able to use to wrap a method which takes `Any` because you cannot extend `Any`. In this case, the type argument to `KeyedDecodingContainer.decode` is a `Decodable`, so we wrap this method in an extension to `Decodable`. We repeat the same process for `Encodable` and `KeyedEncodingContainer.encode` to get encoding functionality.

Now, `[String: AnyDynamicCodable]` conforms to `Codable`.

If you want to use this approach but with structs, consider using a lightweight class wrapper such as

```swift
final class DynamicCodableWrapper<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let value: T
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

You may even want to build this in to your `AnyDynamicCodable` type to make some kind of `AnyCodable` type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the solution you are looking for.

```
import Foundation

struct ContactModel: Codable {
    let name: String
}

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

var map = [String: Codable]()

map["contact"] = ContactModel(name: "John")
let data = try! encoder.encode(map["contact"] as! ContactModel)

let result = try! decoder.decode(ContactModel.self, from: data)

debugPrint(result)
```

This will print the following.

```
ContactModel(name: "John")
```

Comment: Astralis, I will update my question to see if I can make the case more clear

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can consider is defining two different structs, each with a different data type for the field that changes. If the first decode fails, then try decoding with the second data type like this:

```
struct MyDataType1: Decodable {
    let user_id: String
}

struct MyDataType2: Decodable {
    let user_id: Int
}

do {
    let myDataStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyDataType1.self, from: jsonData)

} catch let error {
    // look at error here to verify it is a type mismatch
    // then try decoding again with type MyDataType2
}
```