# Swift - What if the value in a key-value dictionary contained another key-value pair inside it?

Tags: swift, dictionary, key

According this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129401/determining-if-swift-dictionary-contains-key-and-obtaining-any-of-its-values), to obtain the corresponding value in a dictionary if the key is known:

```
let val = dict[key]
```

But what if a dictionary is in this form (would this be called a Dictionary within a Dictionary?):

```
var myDict : [String:[String:Int]] = [String:[String:Int]]();
```

In my code:

```
var scores : [String:[String:Int]] = [player : [sport: point]]();

var player :  String = "";
var sport : String = "";
var point : Int = 0;
```

and I have a function that passes a player's name as a parameter and want to obtain a sum of all his points in Double, i.e.

```
public func sumPoints(playerName : String) -> Double? {

       let val = scores[playerName]
       var sum : Double = 0;

       for item in val {

           // I have trouble how to separate the 'point' from [sport : point] then parse it to Double

           // Here, my value is [sport : point] with the key being [playerName] (or 'player');  but I only want to extract the 'point' not 'sport'

           // Because if I do the following:

           sum += item; // Error:  value of optional type '[String : Int]?' not unwrapped               
       }

   return sum;

}
```

I just want to extract `point` from the `[player: [sport:point]]`.

Comment: What is with all the semicolons? This is Swift, not Objective-C. They are optional, and should only be used if you put multiple statements on a single line (and don't put multiple statements on a single line.)

Comment: @DuncanC  It's just carried-over habit from coding in Java.

Comment: Ok, I came from C, C++ and Objective-C, which are all also full of semicolons. Swift programmers don't use semicolons. Learn not to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
public func sumPoints(playerName : String) -> Int? {

      var sum : Int = 0

      if let val = scores[playerName]  
      { 

         for value in val.values {
            sum = sum + value          
         }

        return sum
      }

      return nil
   }
```

Comment: That was my first attempt actually, and it game me the same error (value of optional type '[String : Int]?' not unwrapped)

Comment: Do not force cast the dictionary access. There might be no entry for the given playerName.

Comment: Why iterate the keys? Just iterate the values.

Comment: I'd remove the semicolons. And I'd return `nil` if there is no matching player. But that's just me. :)

Comment: Can you return nil from a non-optional function?

Comment: I see no more { , I will make it Int?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get the value for a key in a dictionary, the return value is of optional type (as the key's value might not actually exist). So you have to unwrap the optional to actually use the value (if it exists).

Here's a snippet:

```
var scores = ["Jake": ["Soccer": 2]]

public func sumPoints(playerName : String) -> Double? {
    if let playerScores = scores[playerName] {
        var sum : Double = 0
        for score in playerScores {
            sum += Double(score.value)
        }
        return sum
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}

print(sumPoints(playerName: "Jake"))
```

Comment: You should return `nil` is `playerScores` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

you get get (key, value) like this and do whatever operation you wanton (key, values)

```
 public func sumPoints(playerName : String) -> Double? {



   if let player = scores[playerName] {
       var sum = 0.0
       for (key, value) in player {

         sum += value          
        }
      return sum;
   }else {
       return nil
   }


}
```

Hope this will helps

Comment: 1. `player` will be optional. 2. `sum` is an `Int`. You can't return that for a `Double`. 3. You should return `nil` if the playerName isn't found.

Comment: I would move the declaration of `sum` inside the `if` but otherwise looks good.

Comment: i change that too hope this will answer your question