# Dictionary Key Present or Not?

Tags: swift

Can you please help me to Make an extension in swift of Dictionary to find whether key is present or not? I want to use this extension in through out my program.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Are you able to do it without an extension then add that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining if Swift dictionary contains key and obtaining any of its values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129401/determining-if-swift-dictionary-contains-key-and-obtaining-any-of-its-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this extension of Dictionary to check whether key is exist or not.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func contain(_ key: Key) -> Bool {
      return self[key] != nil
    }
}
```

i.e

```
let dict = ["temp" : 2, "temp2" : false, 501 : "2"] as [AnyHashable : Any]

dict.contain("temp") // true
```